# Unable to access this page using WebResponse c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

i am trying to access this page :
http://tawn.tnau.ac.in/General/BlockWiseSummaryPublicUI.aspx?EntityHierarchyOneKey=1&lang=en
Code is as follows :

```
String strResult;
WebResponse objResponse;
WebRequest objRequest = System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(strURL);

objResponse = objRequest.GetResponse();
// the using keyword will automatically dispose the object 
// once complete
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(objResponse.GetResponseStream()))
{
   strResult = sr.ReadToEnd();
   // Close and clean up the StreamReader
   sr.Close();
}
```

it's working fine while accessing others page .I tried to access this page using Mozila but not accessible while it's working on Chrome.

Pl let me know the solution.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If I try to enter the page by clicking the URL I get a message saying that the session is expired. You probably need to login or obtain some kind of cookie prior to performing the request.

Comment: but it working on Chrome

Comment: Try accessing the page while you have fiddler or a similar sniffer running. I guarantee you that there is either a cookie or an authorization header. Or try resetting chrome or access the url in incognito mode. You won't get access.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not browser related. Your code should work fine. However, when you make a request you may need to provide some credentials to access that page.

The request will generally be redirected to a page if you don't provide credentials, which is what's happening in your case.

Comment: There is no credential required to access this page.